# Generating list of iterators from list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists and my goal is to create the list of iterators corresponding to the slices of these lists.

My original attempt is as follows (this is minimal "working" example without most of the unrelated logic):

```
my_lists = [1,2,3], [6,7,8]

iterators = []
for my_list in my_lists:
    it = (my_list[i] for i in range(1,3))
    iterators.append(it)

print(next(iterators[0]))
```

Unfortunately this does not work as intended as the scope of the iterator is shared and the `my_list` variable is thus identical in all the iterators. Meaning that the message of the print is `6` and not `1` as desired.

I am quite struggling to come up with some clean solution. All my attempt to get one fails. They either create unnecessary lists, like:

```
    it = iter(my_list[1:3])
```

and

```
    it = iter([my_list[i] for i in range(1,3)])
```

are unnecessarily clutterring:

```
def apply_range(l, start, stop):
    return (l[i] for i in range(start, stop))
...
    it = apply_range(my_list, 1, 3)
```

or outright hack-ish:

```
    it = (lambda l: (l[i] for i in range(1,3)))(my_list)
```

or iterate from the starts of the lists:

```
from itertools import islice
...
    it = islice(my_list, 1, 3)
```

Please note that the code i need is a bit more complicated than in the first snippet (i.e. start and stop of the range is computed -- i.e. not constant -- and I need more than just first element of first iterator -- in particular I combine them in one iterator with inner logic to pick correct iterator to select next element from).

Comment: Are you just looking for `iterators = [islice(l, 1,3) for l in my_lists]`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this will iterate from the start of the `l` if I am not mistaken (which is a bit problem as the start is not usually `1`). Furthermore, the original logic is complicated enough not to fit in one-line list comprehension

Comment: Oh, yes, it will iterate through the list up to the start. It's hard to answer this question since you say you don't want clutter, but also say things are more complicated than shown.

Comment: I am sorry I guess I am stressing "more complicated" too much, essentially the boundaries for `range` are computed (via a function) and the integrators are then further processed. As for the clutter the problem there is just that when you see "apply range" is a kind of function that when you see it you say to yourself "why is such function even there" that is something I want to a avoid

Comment: I don't see why `itertools.islice(my_list, mystart, mystop, mystep)` wouldn't be the correct way like [Mark Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623/mark-meyer) said. Just remember that Python uses 0-based indexing. So start at `0 (or whatever)` to a maximum of `len(my_list) - 1`.

Comment: using a helper function *is less cluttering and more organized and that function makes perfect sense.*

Comment: @Basile it's correct but unnecessarily inefficient. The helper function is the best solution.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for the comment. So far it seems as it is indeed the best possible solution. I just don't feel comfortable with writing the function for something that simple list comprehension is capable of (well, short of required scoping...)

Comment: @Drecker to be frank, I am of the opinion that writing functions for things is almost always the right way to go, as it provides for self-documenting code and encapsulation. To say it another way, I think it would improve the code *regardless of this issue*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your original code is that the generator expressions need to use the `my_list` variable from the outside scope. Because that variable changes as the loop continues to run, all the iterators end up yielding values from the last list in the input.

You can fix this by encapsulating the creation of the generator in a function. The function will have its own namespace where the specific list to be iterated on will be bound to a local variable (that won't change based on outside code). The function can either be a generator function, or it can be a normal function that returns a generator expression (the two approaches are almost identical).

```
def make_iter(lst, start, stop):
    # this loop could be replaced by `return (lst[i] for i in range(start, stop))`
    for i in range(start, stop):
        yield lst[i]

my_lists = [1,2,3], [6,7,8]

start = 1
stop = 3
iterators = [make_iter(lst, start, stop) for lst in my_lists]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I even mention similar approach in the original post, the reason why I am reluctant to use it is, that it just feels weird to create function for something that can be done with simple lost comprehension (short of creating new scope). Nevertheless, so far it seems as the best option...

Comment: Unfortunately there's not really a good way to get another scope for a generator expression. When creating a `lambda`, you can use a default argument to capture the variable e.g. `callbacks = [lambda i, lst=lst: lst[i] for lst in list_of_lists]`. I don't think there's any equivalent for a generator expression.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple neat code that I think satisfies you desire to make some iterators;

```
my_lists = [1,2,3], [6,7,8]
iterators = []
for my_list in my_lists:
  iterators.append(iter(my_list))
```

allows you to access each "iterator" and the values by using "next";

```
next(iterators[1])
>>> 6
next(iterators[1])
>>> 7
```